# API>23 - java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: java, android, ssl

I have a problem with SSL connection on Nexus 5x (API 25) and Galaxy S7 (API 24), on another devices with API 19 and API 21 I have no problems.

```
W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
W/System.err: at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:361)
```

Could you please explain, how can I solve this problem?

Add:

```
 TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
 KeyStore keyStoreCA = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
 keyStoreCA.load(null, null);
 Certificate certServer = ks.getCertificate("Server");
 if (certServer != null)
 Log.d("###", "certServer=" + certServer.toString());
 keyStoreCA.setCertificateEntry("Server", certServer);
 tmf.init(keyStoreCA);
```

Comment: Does the server have a certificate from a generally recognized CA, or is it perhaps self-signed? In any case, you can independently verify the certificate chain using open-ssh

Comment: No, the server have self-signed certificate. Why this work on older Android versions?

Comment: One possibility is that the  CAs trusted by default are different in different versions. You might need to add this cert's CA certificate to the local TrustStore. http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/https-with-client-certificates-on might help with that.

Comment: I'm doing it. I added code into main question.

Comment: The solution to the problem I found here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624684/ssl-handshake-exception-while-connecting-over-https-using-self-signed-certificat). Is this a safe solution?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, Do you managed to solve it? If yes, can u help me?